# Cannot insert data after one post

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have two tables. The first table works fine but the other table--`signup`--after one post it won't insert any more rows.

I'm also getting this error:

```
(node:7192) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 
11 error listeners added to [Connection]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

My controller.js:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var uuid = require('uuid');
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');


var con = mysql.createConnection({
    connectionLimit : 5,
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : '',
  
    multipleStatements: true  
});

var genRandomString =function(length){
    return crypto.randomBytes(Math.ceil(length/2))
    .toString('hex')
    .slice(0,length);
};
var sha512 =function(password,salt){
    var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha512',salt);
    hash.update(password);
    var value =hash.digest('hex');
    return{
        salt:salt,
        passwordHash: value
    };
};

function saltHashPassword(userPassword){
    var salt =genRandomString(16);
    var passwordData =sha512(userPassword,salt);
    return passwordData;
}

exports.register = function(req,res,next){
    var pd =req.body;
    var uid =uuid.v4();
    var plaint_password =pd.password;
    var hash_data = saltHashPassword(plaint_password);
    var password =hash_data.passwordHash;
    var salt =hash_data.salt;

    var name =pd.name;
    var email =pd.email;
    con.query('SELECT * FROM user where email=?',[email],function(err,result,fields){
        con.on('error',function(err){
            console.log('[mysql ERROR]',err);
        });
        if(result && result.length)
            res.json('User alredy exists');
        else
        {
            con.query('INSERT INTO `user`(`unique_id`, `name`, `email`, `password`, `salt`, `created`, `updated`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,Now(),Now())',[uid,name,email,password,salt],function(err,result,fields){
                con.on('error',function(err){
                    console.log('mysql ERROR',err);
                    res.json('Register error:',err);
                });
                res.json('Register Succesful!!');
            })
        }
    });
};

exports.signup =function(req,res,next){
    var p =req.body;
    //var uid =uuid.v4();
    var name =p.name;
    var organization=p.organization;
    var email =p.email;
    var contact =p.contact;

    con.query('SELECT * FROM vendor where organization=?',[organization],function(err,result,fields){
        con.on('error',function(err){
            console.log('[mysql ERROR]',err);
        });
        if(result && result.length)
            res.json('vendor alredy exists');
        else
        {
            con.query('INSERT INTO `vendor`( `name`, `organization`, `email`, `contact`, `created`, `updated`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,Now(),Now())',
                [name,organization,email,contact],function(err,result,fields){
                con.on('error',function(err){
                    console.log('mysql ERROR',err);
                    res.json('Register error:',err);
                });
                res.json('Vendor Registerd!!');
            })
        }
    });

};

/*exports.imei =function(req,res,next){
    
    
     
}*/
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the spec, I'd remove the 'connectionLimit : 5' from your mysql connection constructor. I believe that 5 connections might be too little, also the spec only gives that option for a pool creation.

Answer (score 0):

## suggestion

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({
        connectionLimit : 5,
        host     : 'localhost',
        user     : 'root',
        password : '',
        database : '',
      
        multipleStatements: true  
    });
```

## to

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({
            connectionLimit : 5,
            host     : 'localhost',
            user     : 'root',
            password : '',
            database : '',
            connectionLimit : 50,
            multipleStatements: true  
        });
```

I added `connectionLimit` test out various number of connection limits

Comment: I don't think the problem is with just that is exports.signup okay?